# Regular expression for vector copy

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, grep

I want to search my codebase for occurrences, where people copy e.g. vectors.
Now I tried this with a regular expression `vector<.*>[ ]+` both in *Visual Studio 2010* and *grep*, but I seem to have gotten something very wrong, since it does not work.
Could someone point out a correct variant, which works on one of these?

---

EDIT:
I am trying to match stuff like `vector<foo> blub = othervec;`

Comment: Can you please provide some examples of what you are trying to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
vector<[^>]*>\s+
```

where the `[^>]*` character class will keep matching until it finds the closing `>` and `\s+` will find one or more whitespace characters.

To not have to escape the `+` in grep, you'll need to use the `-E` flag. Alternatively, you can escape `+` as `\+`:

```
$ cat file
vector<foo> blub = othervec;
$ grep -E 'vector<[^>]*>\s+' file
vector<foo> blub = othervec;
$ grep 'vector<[^>]*>\s\+' file
vector<foo> blub = othervec;
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work in Visual Studio 2010 or grep.

Comment: Thanks. Based on that I now use: `vector<[^>]*>\s+.*=`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
vector<.*?>.*?;
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work in Visual Studio 2010 or grep.